# Property of AJAX cannot be read

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to send an email using a button with AJAX via a POST Call.

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="SendEmail()">Confirm</a>
<script>
    var SendEmail = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Bestellung/SendMailToUser",


            success: function (data) {
                alert ("Success")

            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

I always get this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined

I tried also to change `$.ajax` to `jQuery.ajax` but it didn't work !

Comment: Looks like jQuery is not loaded on your page. Can you confirm that jQuery is loaded? This can be checked by typing `$.fn.jquery` in your browser console.

Comment: Check if jQuery is defined, that looks like most possible. Add jsfiddle link if you can.

Comment: ok I will try and let you know

Comment: thx guys, you have both right, it was a beginner error, I forgot to include the JQuery script in my page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to the jQuery script tag not being included on your page just like the comments mentioned. The snippet below shows the same error when the jquery script tag is missing:

```js
 var SendEmail = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Bestellung/SendMailToUser",


            success: function (data) {
                alert ("Success")

            }
        })
    }
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="SendEmail()">Confirm</a>
```

Add this tag into your page to fix the error:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
    var SendEmail = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Bestellung/SendMailToUser",


            success: function (data) {
                alert ("Success")

            }
        })
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="SendEmail()">Confirm</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that I include it but it was not existed ! copy/past mistake